# boolean variable automatically initializes when changing viewcontrollers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

In My application contain five different tabs. When I switch between tabs initialization of boolean variable automatically called again and again.
When I put a breakpoint on **declaration/initialization** variable it will be automatically called. This will leads to change my boolean variable value to **true**. Please go through the following code
How to resolve this issue. Please help me

```
class HomeViewController: BaseViewController {

    var isEnabled: Bool = true

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        isEnabled = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: just remove the code in `viewWillAppear `?...

Comment: You can use a global variable if you need your Boolean in different controllers.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are trying to achieve. I'm sorry but there is a lot of codesmell.

Comment: dont get this ;) please provide context - I agree with @naresh

Comment: and never use global variables

Answer (score 1):

You are using tab view for your app. When you switch from one tab to other tab `viewWillAppear` called and your boolean variable `isEnabled` is set to `true` and when move to new tab it called `viewWillDisappear` and set to false. If you don't want to change in `isEnabled` variable then remove from `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` then value will not be changed. You will get last value assigned to variable.

`viewDidLoad` method will call only once a life time of `viewController` and that is when `viewController` object will first load in memory. where as `viewWillAppear` method will call every time when a view will appear to screen or you can say will be topViewController...

> Explanation: Tab1 associated with `viewController1` and `tab2` is associated with `viewController2`. Now when you will run your app and you will see tab one is selected and `viewController1` is on view and you want to change to `tab2`, when you will tap on `tab2` then `tabVieController2's` object will create and load to memory first time hence its `viewDidLoad` method will call, and soon after that it will appear to window and  `viewWillAppear` will also get call. Now if you you try changing tabs by click on them only `viewWillAppear` methods will get called for both, as they are in memory already.